# Array sorting in ascending and descending order

Tags: php

i want to write a code in php which will sort my array(1,4,3,5,6,2,7,9,8) in ascending and descending order on clicking there respective buttons? How to do this please help.

Comment: What you have done so far? code please.

Comment: *"i want to write a code in php"* -- what stops you?

Comment: <?php
<form name="Email Header" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  
<button type="submit" name="asc_sort" id="asc_sort" class="button" value="1">Sort</button>
 </form>




if(isset($_POST['asc_sort']) && !empty($_POST['asc_sort']) && $_POST['asc_sort']==1)
{
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message_id ASC";

}else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message_id DESC";
}

echo $sql;
?>

i have don this but its not working

Comment: @ARITRAPUTATUNDA Add your source code to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I offer the following solution:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="but1" value="ASC">
<input type="submit" name="but2" value="DESC">
<?php

$a = [1,4,3,5,6,2,7,9,8];
if (isset ($_REQUEST['but1'])) {
    sort ($a);
    print_r($a);
}
if (isset ($_REQUEST['but2'])) {
    rsort ($a);
    print_r($a);
}
?>

</form>
```